# Heroku API: capture output of a command run on a one-off dyno

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

How do I capture the output of a command being run on a one-off dyno via the API?

For example:

```
heroku = PlatformAPI.connect("...")

heroku.dyno.create(
  app_name,
  attach: false,
  command: "ls"
)
```

This just returns the dyno creation response. It does not include the output of the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the attach argument to true, it will stream the output. To actually get the stream, you should look at the response to dyno create and find the value of `attach_url`. You should be able to pass this to a rendezvous client (like the rendezvous gem) to read info, more details on that here: https://github.com/heroku/rendezvous.rb

Comment: Is this a well-known protocol? There's zero documentation or links in the Heroku docs. :( Is there a Python library to access these streams?

Comment: It is almost a well known protocol. If I recall correctly it is http chunked encoding, except you do NOT interpret two consecutive "\r\n" as the end of the request. Instead, "\r\n" is basically used as a keep-alive, so you should continue until you choose to explicitly stop listening. Unfortunately, in my experience this usually means you have to make a custom client.